# How to link to youtube from a .url file so that it plays on Firefox without Flash?

Tags: html, flash, firefox, explorer

With my software installer I include a tutorial.url file that points to a youtube tutorial. It has worked fine for years. But now there is a problem with Firefox 37.01 as default browser if no Flash player is installed, so youtube uses the Html5 player instead.

The content of the tutorial.url file:

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K9k-wVDwYtw
IconFile=C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHELL32.dll
IconIndex=130
```

Double clicking on the tutorial.url works fine if Flash Player is installed, but if not a file save dialog is displayed. Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgTDU.png

The strange thing is that if instead of launching the tutorial.url file I paste the video URL (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K9k-wVDwYtw) directly to Firefox it plays just fine with the html5 player.

Is there any workaround? Can a .url file with a link to Youtube be created that works on Firefox without the flash player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the equivalent Youtube embed URL. ie:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/K9k-wVDwYtw
```